# Stress, Residual stresses

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, stress-strain

From a mechanics book http://goriely.com/wp-content/uploads/Pages-from-Interdisciplinary-Applied-Mathematics-45-Alain-Goriely-auth.-The-Mathematics-and-Mechanics-of-Biological-Growth-Springer-Verlag-New-York-2017-1.pdf (page 45), they wrote:

" *Suppose we have 3 identical elastic rods a, b and c. Suppose they are glued where b is in the middle making a sandwich shape. They are constrained so that they only deformed along their lengths. Now let the middle rod grow uniformly in length. To preserve the integrity of the composite body and prevent it from breaking apart, the middle rod must be in a state of compression and the outer rods must be in a state of tension. As a result, this structure has developed residual stresses.* "

1. How does compression and increase in length is related? I thought that compression means decreasing in length!
2. The "tension" in rod a and c is what exactly? Isn't it a result of compression? Or due to the fact that also rods a and will increase in length.
3. Can we consider residual stress as elastic?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you know how to draw a [free-body diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_body_diagram)? This will clarify most of your issues here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that the three rods are glued together along their lengths (so that they are in parallel).  If only the middle rod were heated, and it were not attached to the other two rods, it would increase in length (due to thermal expansion) without developing any stress.  But, since the middle rod is constrained by the other two, it is not able to increase in length as much as if it were unconstrained; this constitutes compression of the middle rod relative to its new unconstrained length, and results in compressive stress.  Meanwhile, the growth of the middle rod causes the other two rods to grow in length (even though they are not heated), and this causes them to develop tensile stress.

So the compressive stress in the middle rod is the result of both thermal expansion and axial compression, while the tensile stress in the other two rods is the result of purely axial extension.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the text what is the source of the increase in length of the middle section. In order to reach the conclusion, we can suppose that it has a bigger length than the other two. But was constrained to have the same length during the assembly. For example, by cooling it previously, or heating the other two.

After they are firmly joined together, and the temperature equalize, the middle bar are under residual compression and the other two under residual tensile stress.